# Switching JPanels in a JFrame without CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

How can I switch Panels with ScrollPanes in a Frame? I've tried many possible ways but cannot come up with a solution to. 
Actually this is one of the Java Problems my professor gave me and I needed to accomplish this by not using other layouts (such as CardLayout) and I should use the null layout only. Additional classes are allowed as long as I maintain these three classes and the scroll pane.

```
public class MainDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    panel1 p1 = new panel1();
    panel2 p2 = new panel2();

    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(panel1.panel);
    Container c = frame.getContentPane();
    jsp.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
    c.add(jsp);

    //codes for panel switching from panel1 to panel2 vice versa


    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.exit_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1058, 600);
    frame.setLocation(100, 50);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}

---------------------------------------------

public class panel1{
    public JPanel panel(){
         JPanel fore = new JPanel();
         fore.setLayout(null);
         fore.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (1024, 600));
         fore.setBackground(Color.decode("#004050"));
         fore.setVisible(true);

         JButton but = new JButton();
         but.setLocation(425, 300);
         but.setSize(100, 35);
         //button action/mouse listener
         fore.add(but);

         return fore;
    }
}

---------------------------------------------

public class panel2{
    public JPanel panel(){
         JPanel fore = new JPanel();
         fore.setLayout(null);
         fore.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (1024, 600));
         fore.setBackground(Color.decode("#004050"));
         fore.setVisible(true);

         JButton but = new JButton();
         but.setLocation(425, 300);
         but.setSize(100, 35);
         //button action/mouse listener
         fore.add(but);

         return fore;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*this is one of the Java Problems my professor gave me and I needed to accomplish this by not using other layouts (such as CardLayout) and I should use the null layout only.*" That is a ridiculous and fruitless assignment. I'll apologize for the Professor. Sorry!

Comment: You can accomplish this by dynamically adding and removing components. Look at [removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll()). That said using null Layout is bad, even as a learning exercise. Also you are missing something that even [Swing's Hello World](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java) does: call `invokeLater` in your main.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I switch Panels with ScrollPanes in a Frame?

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( anotherPanel );
```